# Rsync Exclude MP4's Using Wild Cards For Paths

Tags: command-line, bash, backup, rsync, wildcards

I am wanting to exclude rendered videos (.mp4) from my rsync backups.  However there are some .mp4's I need included in the backup.  The difference is the path where the MP4's to be excluded are located.  What I've tried (unsuccessfully) is:

```
/home/rpiggott/Videos/youTube/*/*.mp4
```

- I am trying to use the wild card /*/ is to match all sub-directories.  Each video has it's own directory.
- The *.mp4 is an attempt to match the rendered video I want to exclude.

I am adding this to the end of [this list](https://github.com/rubo77/rsync-homedir-excludes/blob/master/rsync-homedir-excludes.txt).

This is my syntax for the rsync onto my NAS device

```
sshpass -p PASSWORD rsync -av --del --exclude-from=/var/tmp/ignorelist --numeric-ids /home/rpiggott USER@NAS_IP_ADDRESS:/nfs/rpiggott/
```

Comment: Is it an option for you to run two command lines with `rsync`, one that excludes all mp4 files, and one that backs up the mp4 files that you want?

Comment: This is a cron job,  I am happy to modify it,

Comment: OK. How would you specify the mp4 files, that you want to backup? For example, are all of them **not** in the youtube directory?

Comment: A list of the video files I want to exclude can be generated with this command:  **ls /home/rpiggott/Videos/youTube/*/*.mp4**  Could I pipe this to a text file and then exclude both the generic list and this list of files?  (IE 2 files containing lists of what rsync is to skip)

Comment: I think you can use the option `--exclude-from=` more than once. At least you can try it. Is there some direct way to specify the mp4 files, that you want to backup? Are they in some particular directories, or can they be anywhere except in the `/home/rpiggott/Videos/youTube/` directory tree ?

Comment: How do I do the *ls* without using the *ls alias* I've defined?  By default file size, date and permissions are being included in exclude file being created?

Comment: I've documented the answer

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for sharing your solution :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this is creating a complete **exclude** with the list of all files you aren't wanting included in your **rsync**:

Step 1: Create a text file listing the file names (including path) you are excluding from the rsync backup

```
command \ls /home/rpiggott/Videos/youTube/*/*.mp4 > /var/tmp/youTube_mp4_exclude
```

- The use of **command \ls** ignores the ls alias used within terminal
- The use of (1) **>** overwrites the file created each time the command is run
- The output path - file names must match exactly what **rsync** is searching for.  To eliminate part of the path use this:

  `command \ls /home/rpiggott/Videos/youTube//.mp4 | sed 's:/home/::' > /var/tmp/youTube_mp4_exclude`

Step 2: **cat** the files together

```
cat /var/tmp/ignorelist /var/tmp/youTube_mp4_exclude > /var/tmp/rsync_ignore.txt
```

- Don't forget about file permissions if this is becoming a cron job

Step 3: Change **--exclude-from** to the new file created:

```
sshpass -p PASSWORD rsync -av --del --exclude-from=/var/tmp/rsync_ignore.txt --numeric-ids /home/rpiggott root@mybooklive.local:/nfs/rpiggott/
```

- Remember rsync has a **--dry-run** option to test drive your backup

If you are setting this up as a cron use a **.sh** file with file file permission 755

```
0 3 * * * /home/rpiggott/Backup/daily_backup.sh
```